# como habilito cors en ract.js

Tags: reactjs, cors

estoy haciendo peticiones http en react.js pero me marca el error de cors pero no se que mas hacer ya probe con extension con npm cors y nada funcionar

Adjunto codigo:

````
```import '../css/boton.css';
   import React from 'react';
   import {base64_encode} from 'base-64';


 var headers = new Headers();
 headers.append("Autorization","Basic == ")
 headers.append("Accept", "application/json");
 headers.append("Content-Type", "application/json");
 headers.append("Access-Control-Allow-Origin","*");
 var institution = {method:"GET",headers:headers,redirect:'follow'}

class Boton extends React.Component{


constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      error: null,
      isLoaded: false,
      items: [] 
    };
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
  }
  var = base64_encode = {

  
    _keyStr : "+/=",
  
    
    encode : function (input) {
      var output = "";
      var chr1, chr2, chr3, enc1, enc2, enc3, enc4;
      var i = 0;
  
      input = base64_encode._utf8_encode(input);
  
      while (i < input.length) {
  
        chr1 = input.charCodeAt(i++);
        chr2 = input.charCodeAt(i++);
        chr3 = input.charCodeAt(i++);
  
        enc1 = chr1 >> 2;
        enc2 = ((chr1 & 3) << 4) | (chr2 >> 4);
        enc3 = ((chr2 & 15) << 2) | (chr3 >> 6);
        enc4 = chr3 & 63;
  
        if (isNaN(chr2)) {
          enc3 = enc4 = 64;
        } else if (isNaN(chr3)) {
          enc4 = 64;
        }
  
        output = output +
        this._keyStr.charAt(enc1) + this._keyStr.charAt(enc2) +
        this._keyStr.charAt(enc3) + this._keyStr.charAt(enc4);
  
      }
  
      return output;
    },
  }

 handleClick(){
   
 }

  componentDidMount() {
    fetch(``, institution,{mode: "no-cors"})
    
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(
        (result) => {
          this.setState({
            isLoaded: true,
            items: result.items,
            
          });
          console.log(result);
        },
        (error) => {
          this.setState({
            isLoaded: true,
            error
          });
          
        }
      )
  }


render(){
const { error, isLoaded, items } = this.state;
return(
    <>
    <button type='submit' onClick={this.handleClcik} 
         className='continuar'>continuar</button> 

{error
  ? <div>Error: {error.message}</div>
  : !isLoaded 
        ? <div>Loading...</div>
        : <ul>
             {items.map(item => {
                 return <li key={item.id}>
                  {item.name} {item.price}
                 </li>
             })}
         </ul>}
    </>
 )
}
     }
    export default Boton```
````

Ya intente de todo pero no puedo corregir o habiliar el error que marca el cors no se que mas pueda hacer el proyecto lo estoy corriendo con npm start en la consola del navegador pone que el cors esta desabilitado ya lo intente habilitar y no funciona sigue marcando lo mismo intente con las extenciones que eliminan el cors pasa lo mismo

Comment: [aquí](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/es_es/apigateway/latest/developerguide/how-to-cors.html) te dejo información sobre como habilitar el CORS

Comment: Hoy en dia los programadores se han vuelto demasiado dependiente de los frameworks y las librerías de terceros. Hacer un proyecto en ReactJS no es programar, es simplemente implementar lo que otros programaron. Y como siempre los frameworkistas se justifican con la frase "reinventar la rueda".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tienes que habilitarlo del lado del backend o servidor, ahi le puedes decir que origenes son los que permitirá.

Comment: a ok entonces de aqui no moveria nada si no en otra hoja del codigo pondria el codigo para habilitarlo?